# Web Blast Apache configuration (Error 403)

Tags: apache, blast

I'm trying to run Web Blast 2.2.28+ locally trough Easy PHP Dev Server 13.1 (Apache 2.2, Windows 7),but when I click on search it shows ERROR 403 when I open it within my site or the following message appears (blast.cgi content), when I use directly the blast.html page:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
  #
  # $Id: blast.cgi,v 1.1 2002/08/06 19:03:51 dondosha Exp $
  #
  echo "Content-type: text/html"
  echo ""
  #setenv DEBUG_COMMAND_LINE TRUE
  setenv BLASTDB db
  ./blast.REAL
```

Apache was installed in
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\binaries\apache\bin" and configured as the following (httpd.conf):

```
# Added below to get wwwblast to work
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9/data/localweb/original/cgi-bin/">
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi REAL
  Options Indexes
  Options FollowSymLinks
  Options ExecCGI
  Options Indexes
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

and the blast.html file is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\original\cgi-bin".

In the Apache Access log I found:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2013:19:40:13 -0300] "GET /original/?area=tools HTTP/1.1" 200 1797
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2013:19:44:27 -0300] "POST /original/cgi-bin/blast.cgi HTTP/1.1" 403 1115
```

and in the Apache Error log:

```
[Tue Oct 08 19:44:27.607881 2013] [cgi:error] [pid 6084:tid 1036] [client 127.0.0.1:52298] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9/data/localweb/original/cgi-bin/blast.cgi, referer: http://127.0.0.1/original/cgi-bin/blast.html
```

**I really don't understand a little of Apache, but doesn't I activate ExecCGI in my httpd.conf ? I'm very confused.**

I have been trying all the combinations I could have imagined (changing the path, file name, apache options sequence), but... nothing.

Can somebody help me? I need so bad, I've been trying to make it run since 2012.

Thank you all and sorry for any language problems =).
Dimitrius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, I missed the Windows 7 initially.
Afaik, there is no windows version of the wwwblast binaries. Therefore, what you are trying to do here is not going to work. You have several options:

- switch to supported OS (Linux, MacOs, FreeBSD, Solaris)
- use something else (e.g. [Sequenceserver](http://www.sequenceserver.com/) or [ViroBlast](http://indra.mullins.microbiol.washington.edu/viroblast/viroblast.php))
- try to compile from source on Windows (good luck)

The rest below is just a minor mistake.

---

You seem to have missed the "+"s:

```
 Options +ExecCGI
```

not

```
 Options ExecCGI
```

And also `Options +Indexes` etc. The apache config requires either + or - for boolean options to turn them on or off.

In addition, wouldn't this question be better suited on serverfault because it is about server configuration and not programming?

See:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. I changed the httpd.conf file to:                                                       

`# Added below to get wwwblast to work
 AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
 <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9/data/localweb/original/cgi-bin/">
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi REAL
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>`

But it still not working, the _error just changed to ""couldn't create child process: 720002: blast.cgi"" ERROR 500_
The httpd.connf is the server default, isn't it?

Comment: smth else is wrong: see http://openwetware.org/wiki/Wwwblast. csh is missing. My recommendatio, switch to linux for your server.